# What is the purpose of the + operator in an associated type?

Tags: rust

I need to know the purpose of `+` operator and the `'static` keyword at the end. I understand `'static` refers to the lifetime but what purpose it solves in this code.

```
pub trait Group {
    type ColumnValue: Sized + Clone + Eq + Hash + 'static;

    // ...methods...
}
```

I pulled this code text from a [source file from the llamadb project](https://github.com/nukep/llamadb/blob/b2de13b068ab312faa8b87e9e1ea20a0a72c5c14/src/databasestorage.rs#L14).

Comment: The `+` is a separator between [traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#traits) which `ColumnValue` has to implement. `'static` specifies the lifetime. Have you tried reading [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/#language-reference)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In that context, `type X: Y` means that `X` is some type with bounds `Y`. `+` is a way of combining bounds such that `X` must satisfy *all* of the bounds.

In other words, any `impl` for `Group` must have an associated type `ColumnValue` that is `Sized` *and* `Clone`able *and* `Eq`uatable *and* `Hash`able *and* `'static`.

Thus any code using `T: Group` knows that anything of type `T::ColumnValue` can be stored on the stack (`Sized`), cloned, checked for equality, hashed and does not have a non-`'static` lifetime requirement.